# How to synchronize several calls to the same resource through nodes in cluster?

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, distributed, activiti

I have Spring-boot application which expose one endpoint:

```
/update/1532
```

It can receive one query param "approve" which can have either "false" or "true" as a value.
For example:

```
/update/1532?approve=false
```

The problem is that update endpoint can be called simultaneously with different query param value.

To handle this cases we created singleton Context class which hold Set of id's which are in progress. In the above case it should hold 1532 id after the first call so second request with the same id  will cause to error response: "Id is already in progress".

**This solution worked well till the time we decided to create multiple nodes each going to the same database.
The problem is that each node will contain separate Context with unique set of Id's.**

One of the solution can be  the creation of distributed cache of Id's which can replace Set on Context class.
But I'm not sure that this approach is good.

**Maybe somebody can  suggest better solution for locking inside cluster?**

**P.S.**
Synchronization can't be implemented by using DB transaction as all DB communication is hidden under the hood of Activiti framework.

**Technical inforamtion:**
Spring-boot- 1.5.6;
Activiti- 5.21

Answer (score 2):

You need a common point of infrastructure to handle this.  Without getting into things like distributed locks (which are hard), you should just appoint one node as the "master" and the rest as reader nodes.

Write methods should forward the request (possibly server-side) to the writer node, which can manage local locks to write the data.

Alternatively, if you don't want to forward requests, you can look at messaging to solve this.  Drop a message on a queue for each update, and have the master node purely doing writes without making it handle reads.  This is nice because you get to skip some of the HTTP plumbing to either redirect POSTs (307 redirect), or reconstructing them server-side...

If you insist on trying the distributed lock manager route, please pick a library, don't try and roll your own.  This is a complicated subject, and many things have to be considered (mostly around failure modes, not leaving locks dangling forever, deadlock detection, etc).

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't real time, we typically use hazelcast to replicate the application memory map across nodes. Hazelcast will ensure the update is made for the entire grid before it allows response, so you get near realtime synchronization.

We have one application that successfully maintains distributed state across many hundreds of nodes distributed in multiple data centers using this approach.

Greg